# Create custom page in theme templates

Tags: theming

i am currently working on a custom theme and i would like to know if it is possible to create a custom page which would include some php and would be visible after enabling the theme? or is it maybe better to create pages using drupal front end way and then packing it in installation profile ?

Comment: What do you mean by custom page? What do you mean by "drupal front end way"?

Comment: well i would like a basic page with my php and html code in it. and the page must be visible and accesable straight after enabling the teme so that whoever enables it, doesnt have to create it by themselves

Comment: Yes, Drupal supports that. See my answer.

Comment: I tried creating node--features.tpl.php in my theme templates folder as Features is the page which id like to show, however it had no effect since nothing changed on the site. I tried clearing both server and browser cache. May i ask for some more guidance please?

Comment: updated answer with example.

Comment: I dont need many pages of same content type but 5 separate pages each with its own php function displaying Statistics grabed from db source. So id like to create separated php template for each page. Should i name template files page--statistic1.tpl.php and then the next one page--statistic2.tpl.php? Thank you for ur answers and sorry for asking so much.

Comment: You don't want to be doing db calls in a template. You should do that in a custom module.

Comment: @beth Alright then, if i create a custom module holding the db calls, how can i then display them on a specific page? Or should i create a block rather and then display it in main-content?

Comment: A block is one way to expose your data, depending on what exactly you're trying to show. You could also define a view, make a ctools plugin, or a variety of other ways of exposing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Drupal supports custom pages. This is accomplished in Drupal 7 using a [variety](https://drupal.org/taxonomy/term/35874) of [php templates](http://theming.isaacsonwebdevelopment.com/template-files).

Your template must follow [naming conventions](https://drupal.org/node/1089656) to be picked up and processed.

For example, to use a template on a specific node with node ID 5, of type 'article', you'd name it `node--5.tpl.php` but if you wanted to use it on all articles, you'd use `node--article.tpl.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Drupal supports custom pages.
But with different naming conventions
Follow this link of drupal.org
 https://drupal.org/node/1089656

Answer (score 0):

Yes custom pages are their.
 Like we want to create different home page rather than page.tpl.php 
Just copy page.tpl.php and paste it in your theme (remember to copy it not to cut it)
Then change the name to **page--front.tpl.php** Its in drupal 7 
for drupal 6 its **page-front.tpl.php**